# jQuery Cycle Plugin - Cycling images with php query_posts and display caption using the_excerpt

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

How may I be able to show the correspond captions properly of each cycled image?

PHP:

```
<div id="cycle-gallery">
<?php query_posts("cat=38&showposts=2");  ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
img src="/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Image', true); ?>" alt="Icon for Post     #<?php the_ID(); ?>" </a>
<?php endwhile; ?></div>
<div id="cycle-caption"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<div id="cycle-nav"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#cycle-gallery').cycle({
fx: 'fade',
speed: 'slow',
timeout: 7000,
next: '#nextimg',   
pager: '#cycle-nav',
prevNextClick: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
        $('#cycle-caption').fadeOut().eq(zeroBasedSlideIndex).fadeIn(200);
    },
    pagerClick: function(zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
        $('#cycle-caption').fadeOut().eq(zeroBasedSlideIndex).fadeIn(200);
    }   
});
```

});

Comment: I am using php the_excerpt to display the captions of each image using the query_posts method

Comment: The problem I face is that when the images cycle, the caption does not cycle to correspond to the image it cycles with.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like to me:

Cycle is cycling the `cycle-gallery` element. Which means that each element nested inside that will be cycled.

Try something like

```
<div id="cycle-gallery">
  <div class="cycle-item">    
    <?php query_posts("cat=38&showposts=2");  ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Image', true); ?>" alt="Icon for Post #<?php the_ID(); ?>" /></a>
    <div id="cycle-caption"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- <div id="cycle-nav"></div> -->
  </div> <!-- close cycle-item -->
</div> <!-- close gallery -->
```